# Error when installing package using pip in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm on Windows with Python 3.6.4 installed. Following the Python documentation I typed following on cmd but got error:

```
>py -3.6 -m pip install numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "__main__.py", line 126, in <module>
  File "__main__py__.py", line 60, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '-3.6'
```

`Python 3.6.exe` is in my system PATH. What am I missing here?

Comment: As the error states `-3.6` does not belong on the command line. Have you tried `pip install numpy`?

Comment: `pip install numpy` gives this error: `Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'` . But when I open the cmd in the location of pip3.6.exe  (`C:\Users\durraniu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts`) and then type `pip install numpy` then it works. So, I added this location to System PATH as well. But outside this folder, `pip install` does not work. It throws the same error.